# sort paginator list django template

Tags: django, sorting, templates, paginator

I need to display a very long list in a table in django templates.
since it takes really long to show all the results, I'm using paginator and that way I see the results in no-time. The problem now is that I need to sort this table (by clicking on a columns) in the client side but I could not find any way to to it fast - I either sort each page of the table and it's not a good enough or sort the entire table by using DataTable and it takes forever. any ideas to sort quickly?

Comment: You should be able to use 'order_by' in your view when filtering the results, even with pagination. You just can't order a grouping when using pagination. List the view function, and we can get a better idea of how to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Implement onclick events on your table headlines and handle the sort of your data in your get_queryset method in your views.py with `queryset = queryset.order_by('fieldname')`